# How to inject a service (or component) in a thread in micronaut?

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, micronaut

Environmants:

- JDK: 11.0.7
- OS: Windows 10
- Micronaut: 2.1.2

How to inject a service (or a component) in a thread in micronaut with profile cli-app?

Below link is my code.

[test-multithread-app](https://github.com/wureka/test-multithread-app)

Key portion:

```
@Prototype
class TestWorker implements Callable  {
    private String threadName = Thread.currentThread().name
    @Inject TestService testService

    @Override
    Object call() throws Exception {
        for(int x = 0;x < 20; x++) {
            println("${threadName}: x:${x}, ${testService.getGreeting(threadName)}")
            sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

It throws NullPointerException as below

> 09:08:31.254 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment -
> Established active environments: [cli] managerId: 1 workerCount:1
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getGreeting() on
> null object   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:44)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
> at test.multithread.app.TestWorker.call(TestWorker.groovy:29)   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) stops

Answer (score 1):

Using `@Inject` is a code smell in my book and here we see why.  Your worker *needs* the `TestService` to work (there is no way around it - if it's not there, you get an NPE).

Next you are creating the worker manually - so it does not participate in the dependency injection.  Since you only use the "deklarative" `@Inject`, nothing ever bothers, that the service, that is mandatory, ends up where it is needed.

So your first step here:

Get rid of `@Inject` and add a constructor, that sets the `TestService` - better even make the variable to hold it `final` so all the alarms go off, if you miss to set it in the c'tor

Now if you create the `TestWorker` via `new` you are forced to pass the `TestService` in (well you still can pass `null` etc, but asserts could enforce this).

The other option (regardless, whether you switch to c'tor based injection or you want to still use `@Inject` for some reason), would be to ask the `ApplicationContext` to build your instance.  E.g. `applicationContext.getBean(Testworker)`.

Comment: `Using @Inject is a code smell in my book and here we see why." - @Inject isn't part of the problem.  The problem is that the app is dealing with an instance of `TestWorker` created outside the DI container, so the instance isn't being subjected to DI.  That will be true if you are using `@Inject` or not.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown You maybe have missed the last paragraph then.

Comment: "You maybe have missed the last paragraph then. " - I don't think so.  I read the last paragraph.   I just now read it again.  That paragraph describes another option with a different problem, but I did read it, and I don't think I am mis-reading it.  Maybe I am.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the usage of applicationContext.getBean(TestWorker.class), if there is a constructor with parameters like TestWorker(String foo), how shoud I use applicationContext.getBean(TestWorker.class) and inject a variable into the constructor ?

Comment: Unless the string is something from a @Value i doubt you can. But don't consider me an expert on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating an instance of the worker yourself with `new TestWorker()` at https://github.com/wureka/test-multithread-app/blob/7e8838c7545e18edda8a367b3b966c06d65fc226/src/main/groovy/test/multithread/app/TestManager.groovy#L19.  When you do that, the dependency injection container is not involved so the instance will not be subjected to dependency injection so your `testWorker` property will be null on that particular instance of `TestManager`.

Suggesting an improvement to the design would require an understanding of the surrounding context, but the above explains why you are getting an NPE.